# How can I remove the white gap between the header and background image when using parallax scrolling?

Tags: html, css

So here's the HTML code for my website about a holiday destination (New York). I've so far made a nav bar and implemented parallax scrolling with two background images. I then saw when running the code that there was a white space after the nav bar and the first background image and I'm not sure how to solve this. I've tried changing the padding and margins around but that's not working :( Some help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
 body, html{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
 }

 .container {
     width: 80%;
     margin: 0 50px;
 }

 header{
     background:plum;
     position: relative;
 }

 header::after{
     content: "";
     display: table;
     clear:both;
 }

 .logo{
     width: 100px;;
     height: 60px;
     float: left;
     padding: 0px;
 }

 nav{
     float: inline-end;
     overflow: auto;
 }

 nav ul{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
 }

 nav li{
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 70px;
     padding-top: 20px;
     font-size: 18px;
     position: relative;
 }

 nav a{
     color: black;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;

 }

 nav a:hover{
     color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 }

 nav a::before{
     content: "";
     display: block;
     height: 3px;
     background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     width: 0%;
     transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
 }

 nav a:hover::before{
     width: 100%;
 }

 .bg-one{
     background-image: url("bg-one.jpg");
     height: 100%;
     padding-top: 0;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
     position:relative;     
 }


 .transbox{
     padding: 10px;
     width: 30%;
     background-color: white;
     border: 10px double black;
     opacity: 0.6;
     margin-left: 50px;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 4%;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     display: block;
 }

 .transbox p{
     margin: 5%;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: black;
 }

 h1{
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 65px;
 }

 .first-block{
     height: 100px;
     background-color:rgb(109, 176, 243);
     text-align: center;
     border: 10px double white;
     padding-bottom: 60px;
     vertical-align: auto;
 }

 h3{
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     color: rgb(13, 97, 170);
 } 


 .bg-two{
     background-image: url("bg-two.jpg");    
     height: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
     position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>New York</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
         <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@400&display=swap" 
 rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
     <body>
         <header>
             <div class="container">
             <img src="nyc-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

             <nav>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>

                 </ul>
             </nav>
             </div>
         </header>
         <div class="bg-one">
             <div class="transbox">
                 <h1>NEW YORK</h1>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="first-block">
             <h3>Welcome to the city that never sleeps...</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="bg-two"></div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Conventionally, you'd show an example that is runnable so we don't have to make one ourselves, using something like jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Comment: @Jake I edited and threw into a snippet if that helps.

Comment: @Jake Thanks for the heads up, will make sure to do that next time.

Comment: @Zac thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fully understand what is white space you mean, but try to delete ***margin-top: 4%*** in

```
.transbox{
     padding: 10px;
     width: 30%;
     background-color: white;
     border: 10px double black;
     opacity: 0.6;
     margin-left: 50px;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     display: block;
 }
```

Comment: This actually solved my problem, something as small as that and I didn't even notice! Thanks so much for the help :)

Comment: No problem, sometimes I have the same mistakes :)

Comment: I do actually have a slight problem though, I did that but then I need to position the box slightly lower without creating that whitespace again? Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: Yep, padding for its container or top for this block